Problems with starting waitress-serve via systemd service
Project Environment
I have a Flask-based web service I can start from the command line. The project environment looks like this:
BASEDIR/
    startMyService.sh
    |-venv/
        |-/bin
        |...
    |-/WebService...
    |-Flask-related directories

I am providing a virtual environment to make it run ($BASEDIR is the path, where the project environment is located):
sudo python -m venv ./venv
source $BASEDIR/venv/bin/activate
waitress-serve --port=8080 --call 'WebService:create_app'

Note: when doing this, I see, that the venv has been activated by the (venv) prefixing the command line.
Shell Script for Starting WebService
I wrapped the commands above in a shell script startMyService.sh with the following code ($BASEDIR is the directory where the script is located):
#!/bin/bash

# activate venv located in same directory as this file
python -m venv $BASEDIR/venv
source $BASEDIR/venv/bin/activate
pip install waitress
pip install flask
pip install ... whatever

# re-install the web application provided as wheel
$BASEDIR/venv/bin/pip3 uninstall myapp --yes
$BASEDIR/venv/bin/pip3  install $BASEDIR/dist/myapp-0.1.0-py3-none-any.whl --force-reinstall

# find already running instances of the service and kill them
PROCESSID=`ps aux | grep "WebService:create_app" | grep -v "grep" | awk '{print $2}'`

if [[ $PROCESSID != "" ]]
then
    echo "killing existing instances of WebService with PID $PROCESSID"
    kill -9 $PROCESSID
fi

# start webserver in the background
echo "Starting webService..."
waitress-serve --port=8080 --call 'WebService:create_app'

Systemd Service causing Problems
Now I would like to make a systemd service from that script. Currently, the .service-File looks like this:
[Unit]
Description=My web application
Documentation=some url

[Service]
PIDFile=/run/pidfile.pid
Type=simple
ExecStart=theApplicationDirectory/startMyService.sh
ExecStop=/bin/kill -9 $MAINPID

[Install]
WantedBy=default.target

When I start the service via sudo systemctl start myservice.service the service ends up in status "dead"/incative. journalctl show some indication:
...
Starting status webpage in testing mode
May 06 11:33:00 servername startMyService.sh[726211]: Error: Bad module 'WebViewer'
May 06 11:33:00 servername startMyService.sh[726211]: Usage:
May 06 11:33:00 servername startMyService.sh[726211]:     waitress-serve [OPTS] MODULE:OBJECT

To me it seems that the activation of the virtual environment in the shell script does not happen and the service wants to start with the default Python instead of the venv.

Not related to your problem, but why would you use sudo to create a virtual environment? That's completely crazy.

@tripleee sorry, that was a leftover from attempty to make that work as service. The script works without sudo.
